# SystemMediaControls.ButtonPressed event fires twice

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to add a media player control to SystemMediaControls. But, I have an issue here. When you pressed it, it occurs twice. Please see code below:

```
using Windows.Media;
using . . .

public class Main{
    public static SystemMediaTransportControls systemMediaControls;
    public Main(){
        this.InitializeComponent();
        systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
        int num = 0;
        systemMediaControls.ButtonPressed += async (SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            num++;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Event number: {num}");
        };
   }
}
```

I proved it with debug logs, and the debug logs are:

> Event number: 1
> Event number: 1
> Event number: 2
> Event number: 2
> Event number: 3
> Event number: 3

I have no idea where's the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my fault. I put event on MainPage main function. The mistake is, I call MainPage more than once in the App.cs. For example:

```
void LaunchApp() {
    new MainPage();
     ...
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

So it initializes twice. That's why the event also fires twice. I have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> SystemMediaControls.ButtonPressed event fires twice

I have tested with official code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls). Unfortunately, we can't reproduce this problem, Derive official tutorial, if you want to custom  `SystemMediaTransportControls`, we need to sync playback status To `MediaPlayerState` at fist. and control the media player in button pressed event.

```
switch (mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackState)
            {
                case MediaPlaybackState.None:
                    systemMediaControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
                    break;

                case MediaPlaybackState.Opening:
                    // This state is when new media is being loaded to the MediaPlayer [ie.
                    // Source].  For this sample the design is to maintain the previous playing/pause 
                    // state before the new media is being loaded.  So we'll leave the PlaybackStatus alone
                    // during loading.  This keeps the system UI from flickering between displaying a "Play" 
                    // vs "Pause" software button during the transition to a new media item.
                    break;

                case MediaPlaybackState.Buffering:
                    // No updates in MediaPlaybackStatus necessary--buffering is just
                    // a transitional state where the system is still working to get
                    // media to start or to continue playing.
                    break;

                case MediaPlaybackState.Paused:
                    if (mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position == TimeSpan.Zero)
                        systemMediaControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
                    else
                        systemMediaControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
                    break;

                case MediaPlaybackState.Playing:
                    systemMediaControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
                    break;

            }
```

For more detail please refer [Manual control of the System Media Transport Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls)